# JodaTime not working

Tags: android, jodatime, android-jodatime

I an new to android and am having trouble working with jodatime. I am getting the same error as many people on here and I have tried all the suggestions but nothing is working for me. I am trying to display the variables a user selected from a date and time picker e.g. 'dayNow, monthNow' etc into one combined variable called 'timeselected' and set it to a textbox so then I can carry out a calculation in jodatime further on down.

The code is as follows:

```
            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timeselected);
            DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");
            String formattedtime = fmt.print(dateTime);
            CalculateButton.setText(formattedtime);

            // Plus some hours, minutes, and seconds to the original DateTime.
            DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");

            DateTime dateTime1 = dateTime.plusHours(timeadded);
            String endtimecalc = fmt2.print(dateTime1);
            TextView endtime = (TextView) findViewById(endtimetextView);
            endtime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            endtime.setText(endtimecalc);

            String timeselected = dayNow + "-" + monthNow + "-" + yearNow + " " + hourNow + ":" + minuteNow;

            DateTime datetimselected = DateTime.parse(timeselected);

            usertimeselection.setText((CharSequence) datetimselected.toDate());

        }
    });
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: com.almac.tracker, PID: 29114
>                                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2017-11-23 T 4:56" is malformed at " T 4:56"
>                                                                          at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)
>                                                                          at org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(DateTime.java:160)
>                                                                          at org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(DateTime.java:149)
>                                                                          at com.almac.tracker.CreateLine$5.onClick(CreateLine.java:274)
>                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6219)
>                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24482)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: There must be a dup of this, but Joda Time is fussy about formats; you need to separate the date components with `-` not `/`, for a start. See [the docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser\(\)) for more info - `8-11-2017 T 4:16:00` might be needed to pass, for instance.

Comment: I have added all the relevant code above if you could take a look please

Answer (score 1):

From [`DateTime.parse(String str)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse(java.lang.String)) documentation:

> Parses a DateTime from the specified string.
>
> This uses ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().

Your datetime string is not valid for the `ISODateTimeFormat`, it does not accept `/` but `-`.

So **either** change your `/` to `-` and comply to the rule:
`date-opt-time = date-element ['T' [time-element] [offset]]` (see that **'T'** between the date and time elements!)
So your datetime string should be like this:

```
String timeselected = yearNow + "-" + monthNow + "-" + dayNow + "'T'" + hourNow + ":" + minuteNow;
DateTime datetimselected = DateTime.parse(timeselected);
```

**either** use your own formatter via the `DateTime.parse(String str, DateTimeFormatter formatter)` method.

**UPDATE 1**

After running some tests indeed the `'T'` is not accepted by the default parser. A string that passes from the parser is :

```
"2017-11-23T04:56"
```

So make sure no spaces exist between the **date section**, the **"T"** character and the **time section**.

```
String timeselected = yearNow + "-" + monthNow + "-" + dayNow + "T" + hourNow + ":" + minuteNow;
```

**UPDATE 2**

Attaching my test code for the parser

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String timeselected = "2017-11-23T04:56";
        DateTime datetimselected = DateTime.parse(timeselected);
        System.out.println(datetimselected.toDate());
    }
}
```

output:

```
Thu Nov 23 04:56:00 EET 2017
```

Comment: @Almac3 I have updated my answer with the correctly formatted datetime string for `DateTime.parse`

Comment: tried that but it doesn't accept it, also we are trying to do a calculation between 2 date times....does the format matter in order to do the calculation behind the scenes? thankyou

Comment: Oh I see it needs first year then month then day so your string should be: `yearNow + "-" + monthNow + "-" + dayNow + "'T'" + hourNow + ":" + minuteNow;` I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: its still not letting me add the public static DateTime line

Comment: What "public static DateTime line" ??? From my answer? This is an alternative (keyword: **either**)! I will update my answer to remove this if it is confusing

Comment: how do I convert the string 'time selected' to a datetime?

Comment: Its all in my answer (and in your posted code) check line: `DateTime datetimselected = DateTime.parse(timeselected);`

Comment: ok yes, I need it as a datetime and now it continues to crash with your code - says "invalid format ........ is malformed at 'T 10:58'"

Comment: Post the crash errors, just it crashes is not any useful

Comment: I have added the newest stacktrace in replace of the older one - thank you

Comment: Seen the stacktrace now. Are you sure this is the output from my answer? I have **T** in single quotes and with no spaces whereas in the stacktrace no single quotes appear and there are spaces before and after

Comment: Updated my answer, no single quotes required in **T** character but pay attention to the spaces before and after, there should not be any